# Reduce an equation

Tags: digital-logic, boolean-algebra

How can I use boolean algebra to reduce the following equation? 
$$
\bar{a}\bar{c}+bc+ab
$$
I understand how to get the answer using karnaugh maps, but using simple axioms I am unable to get the solution.

Comment: I don't see much of reduction for this equation except of taking `b` out of brackets...

Comment: However the disjunctive normal form for it is a'c'+b

Comment: @EugeneSh it can actually be simplified quite a bit if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @TomCarpenter Really? Let me see.. I was trusting my intuition..

Comment: @TomCarpenter You are right. But the trick here will be a new variable introduction to denote `a'c'` Not very trivial. Without knowing the final answer it's not that easy to come up with it :)

Comment: @EugeneSh basically, yeah. It's certainly a challenging one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to derive the full answer (I did, but as it appears to be homework, I won't show it), but I will give you some pointers.

As EugeneSh says, use the distributive law to take out the common factor of \$B\$.

Once you have done that, you should apply a DeMorgan's Theorem to make a commonality between the two terms.

Now that there is a commonality, substitute it for another letter (e.g. \$D\$) to make things easier to follow.

Finally you use the law of common identities (or redundancy law) to simplify the new expression.

Substitute back into the final expression the value \$D\$.

---

For reference, I used this table for the names of each rule:

[image: Boolean Simplification Rules]
<sup>[Image source](http://webpages.sou.edu/~nordquip/cs314/notes/n2tNotes.htm)</sup>

Comment: I suppose I could deduce it intuitively. I was hoping for a more elegant solution.

Comment: @j.a456 Formally: 1) factor `b`. 2) de Morgan. 3) Redundant Literal Rule. Elegant enough?

Comment: @j.a456 Updated with correct names. It's been a while, so had to look up the names of each rule again.

Comment: Hm. Apparently some of this stuff has no standard names..

Comment: @EugeneSh. Bits of the table may not even have an official name. Many sources seem to just call the last two on that list as "other identities" or "useful identities" and such, and that's if they mention them at all. They seem to be more just intuition.

Answer (score 0):

$$\bar{a}\bar{c}+bc+ab$$
\$\overline{a + c}+b (a + c)\$ deMorgan's and Distributive

\$\overline{a + c}+b\$ Redundancy (the first term makes the opposite polarity redundant).

\$\bar{a}\bar{c}+b\$ Either answer is equivalent.

$$\bar{a}\bar{c}+bc+ab = \overline{a + c}+b\ = \bar{a}\bar{c}+b$$

This is one solution.  Easier to understand may be expansion of missing terms.

$$\bar{a}\bar{c}+bc+ab$$
\$\bar{a}\bar{c} (b + \bar b) +bc (a + \bar a)+ab(c + \bar c)\$

\$\bar{a}b\bar{c} + \bar{a}\bar{b}\bar c + \color {red}{abc} + \bar abc + \color {red}{abc} + ab\bar c\$ Idempotent - Remove duplicates.

\$\bar{a}b\bar{c} + \bar{a}\bar{b}\bar c + abc + ab\bar c + \bar abc + \color {red}{\bar{a}b\bar{c}} \$ Rearrange. Idempotent - Duplicate as needed.

\$\bar{a}\bar{c} (b + \bar b) + b (ac + a\bar c + \bar a c + \bar a \bar c)\$ Look for common terms.

\$\bar{a}\bar{c}+b\$ Complement

$$\bar{a}\bar{c}+bc+ab = \bar{a}\bar{c}+b$$

[Laws and Theorems of Boolean Algebra](http://www.mi.mun.ca/users/cchaulk/misc/boolean.htm)