# How to do 2 variable XOR

Tags: digital-logic

How do I do (ac XOR bd) + a

I came up with the solution:
a’c’bd + acb’d’ + a

I am not sure if this is correct

Comment: Not correct. Tip: (xy)' = (x' + y').

Comment: Unsure how this is 'electrical engineering'.

Answer (score 0):

Using De Morgan's laws and [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/244655/reduce-an-equation/244656) question and following answers which contain some simplification tables :

```
A^B = A`B + AB`

(AC ^ BD) + A = (AC)`(BD) + (AC)(BD)` +A = (A`+C`)(BD) + (AC)(B`+D`) + A = A`BD + C`BD + AB`C + ACD` + A = A(B`C + CD` + 1) + A`BD + C`BD = A + A`BD + C`BD = A + BD + C`BD = A + BD(C` + 1) = A + BD
```

for learning purposes, if you want to get some clues without going into calculations, it's obvious that `A` is a part of answer because it's ORed with other stuff. and when it is, the `C` is somehow out of it because if the `A=0` then the `C` vanishes and the BD comes out of XOR. if the `A=1`, the output is always 1 beacuse of ORed A. so the solution only depends on BD (first case) and A.